Use website/php to read price data from my PayPal hostedbuttons
I have a paypal business account so that I can accept payments into my paypal account.
Using the static button generator in PayPal to create hosted buttons and links works fine. No problem with that.
On my website I display the item description and the price above the paypal button. And, obviously, the PayPal hostedbutton knows the price.
If I want to change the price I log into my paypal account and change the item price and then log into my website to change the displayed price there too so that both places shows the same price.
What I would like to do is have the page (PHP) on my website connect to paypal and read the current price from the hostedbutton. That way I will only need to change the price in PayPal and my website would automatically show the correct price.
I know how to use my paypal clientid and secret to connect to paypal and get an access_token but is it even possible to read hostedbutton data?
Thanks y'all.

I don't think you'd want to read it from a button as such, that's just a HTML element for display in your page. But presumably it renders based on a setting in your paypal account. I'm not familiar with the specifics but if you know how to connect to paypal's API with an access token, then you should look through the API documentation in the first instance, to see if there's an endpoint which will provide the info you're looking for via a HTTP request

Sorry. Of course I meant that I want to read the data that's related to the button rather than the actual button itself.

Ok. Well that's why you need to look through the API docs and see if you can find a useful endpoint.

I do tend to spend a LONG time googling and looking through documentation before asking questions. In this case I've been googling and reading docs till I'm blue in the face. This ought to work. sorry. Tried to post some code here in the comment. I'll post another question with code.

Just [edit] the current question to show what you've done already  and what we can therefore rule out. No need to ask a duplicate. Otherwise it just reads like you want us to look it all up for you

Thanks. Didn't think of going back to edit the original question. You'll see I don;t ask many questions here so don't know how things are done round here.

It is not possible to read the price from hosted button data. PayPal's hosted buttons are for simple HTML websites with no backend.
For the type of functionality you describe, use a standard PayPal integration and set the price yourself with an API call from your backend.

Alternatively to doing your own integration, there are open source/third-party shopping carts. PayPal has this partner directory as a starting point, though there are many others: https://www.paypal.com/us/business/platforms-and-marketplaces/directory

I'm tending to agree with you. I have code that works in that it doesn't cause any api errors and paypal gives a return value but it's just empty.
I seem to draw a blank with PayPal documentation. I can use a simple hostedbutton which works fine. Or I can create my own checkout page where I collect all the data and just pass it all to PayPal to complete the payment. But one of the solutions I had but didnt like involved me handling personal data that I want to steer away from.
But I also like the look of the paypal frame that is created when using the hosted button, link and QR code.

Somebody voted this answer down? is it ,or is it not, possible to read something like the price from hostedbutton data using the paypal API to connect to my paypal account?

my answer is accurate
